# Parcelable no such file or directory

Tags: android, linker-errors, parcelable

Hello i have a strange error when the application write parcelable.

With the code :

```
package com.android.edl;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;
import com.tools.edl.Tools;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ElementDescription implements Parcelable  {

private int Id;
private String natureText = "";
private String UsureText = "";
private String FonctionnementText = "";
private String EtatText = "";
private Tools tools = new Tools();
private static String table = "edl_ElementDescription";

public ElementDescription (Parcel in)
{
    Id = in.readInt();
    natureText = in.readString();
    UsureText = in.readString();
    FonctionnementText = in.readString();
    EtatText = in.readString();
}
public ElementDescription ()
{

}
public int update(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("natureText", natureText);
    values.put("usureText", UsureText);
    values.put("fonctionnementText", FonctionnementText);
    values.put("fonctionnement", FonctionnementText);
    values.put("etatText", EtatText);
    this.Id = (int) db.insert(table, null, values);
    return this.Id;
}
public void maj(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("natureText", natureText);
    values.put("usureText", UsureText);
    values.put("fonctionnementText", FonctionnementText);
    values.put("fonctionnement", FonctionnementText);
    values.put("etatText", EtatText);
    db.update(table, values, "id=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(Id)});
}
public void init(SQLiteDatabase db,int id)
{
    Cursor description = db.query(table, new String[]{"natureText","usureText","fonctionnementText","etatText","id"}, "id=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
    description.moveToFirst();
    if(description.getCount()>0)
    {
        natureText = tools.isNull(description.getString(0));
        UsureText = tools.isNull(description.getString(1));
        FonctionnementText = tools.isNull(description.getString(2));
        EtatText = tools.isNull(description.getString(3));
        Id = description.getInt(4);
    }
}

public void createXml(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Description");
        if(!tools.isEmpty(natureText))
        {
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "NatureText");
            xmlSerializer.text(natureText);
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "NatureText");
        }
        if(!tools.isEmpty(UsureText))
        {
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "UsureText");
            xmlSerializer.text(UsureText);
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "UsureText");
        }
        if(!tools.isEmpty(FonctionnementText))
        {
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "FonctionnementText");
            xmlSerializer.text(FonctionnementText);
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "FonctionnementText");
        }
        if(!tools.isEmpty(EtatText))
        {
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "EtatText");
            xmlSerializer.text(EtatText);
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "EtatText");
        }
    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Description");
}
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getNatureText() {
    if(natureText==null)
        return "";
    else
        return natureText;
}
public void setNatureText(String natureText) {
    this.natureText = natureText;
}
public String getUsureText() {
        return UsureText;
}
public void setUsureText(String usureText) {
    UsureText = usureText;
}
public String getFonctionnementText() {
    return FonctionnementText;
}
public void setFonctionnementText(String fonctionnementText) {
    FonctionnementText = fonctionnementText;
}
public String getEtatText() {
    return EtatText;
}
public void setEtatText(String etatText) {
    EtatText = etatText;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeInt(Id);
    out.writeString(natureText);
    out.writeString(UsureText);
    out.writeString(FonctionnementText);
    out.writeString(EtatText);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ElementDescription> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<ElementDescription>() {

    public ElementDescription createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ElementDescription(in);
    }

    public ElementDescription[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ElementDescription[size];
        }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

at the line "out.writeString(EtatText)"

When i execute application, for one of ten when i clicked on the item of the listView. When percelable object for send to other activity puts the error :

**"error opening trace file: No such file or directory !"** in infinity loop up to error **"Cannot bind to local 8700 for debugger"**

someone he met you this error please?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Cannot bind to local 8700 for debugger"
```

This happens when we try to launch Android app on the device from Eclipse and the debugger fails to connect to the localhost at the particular port and times out.

**To fix this do the following steps exactly in the order given:**

You are using Base local debugger port 8700.
Plz change it to 8600 or 8601 , restart eclipse and then Try.

**You can do it as follows:**

Under `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS:`

Set Base local debugger port to "8600" or "8601"
Check the box that says "Use ADBHOST" and the value should be "127.0.0.1"

1. Close Eclipse
2. Disconnect USB cable
3. Kill all adb instances on the task manager of your computer
4. Start Eclipse
5. Connect USB cable
6. Launch the application

If this does not help then make sure that you are using IPv4 address for localhost DNS loopback name.

Comment: It's not a solution. The problem it's in parcelable. This error was occured as an item. For other item the error is not occured.

is that it could be the size?

Comment: I use emulator for launch application.

Comment: you can cange that for emulator as well.

Comment: I erased the line out.writeString(EtatText) and the application works.
It's really strange

Comment: That's really strange? But isn't that value important to you?

Comment: It's a important value for application. 
It's possible that size is too large for parcelable? 
I passe a object who contains other objects in parcelable